# SQLalchemy Core, retrive id/s of the updated row/s

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to learn how to use the SQlalchemy core properly and currently, I have this query.

```
        up = Airport.__table__.update().where(Airport.__table__.c.iata_code == iata_code).values(city=city)
```

I am using it to update values in a table that has this structure:

```
class Airport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'airports'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    iata_code = Column(String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    city = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
```

The problem is that after the execution of the update procedure I need the ids of the updated rows.
Is it possible to update the values and obtain the ids in only one query? I would like to avoid to have to perform 2 queries for this operation.

The DBMS I am using is mysql.

Comment: what database is this being run on?

Comment: A classic mysql database

Comment: unfortunately on mysql, this is not possible. you'll need to do two queries. However, on databases that support `insert/update/delete..returning`, such as postgresql, what you seek is doable, check out the sqlalchemy documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-update-returning

Comment: Thank you for these info, I think I will switch to postgresql then

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: *This is for SQLAlchemy ORM, not Core*

Get the object, and update it. SQLAlchemy will update the instance's ID in the same DB round trip.

```
airport = Airport.filter_by(Airport.__table__.c.iata_code == iata_code).first()
airport.city = city
db.session.commit()
print(airport.id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, correct me if I am wrong but you are using, SQLAlchemy ORM. I was trying to avoid using it, I wanted to achieve this only with SQLAlchemy Core functionalities

Comment: @gianlucads Oh, I see. I missed that detail.